# Why doesn't API for Contribution Get work with multiple Financial Type ID values?

Tags: civicontribute, api, contributions

I have this problem on my Joomla 4.6.2 system, and can reproduce it on the Joomla sandbox.  If I use the API Explorer to build a query like:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "id",
  'contact_id' => 2,
  'financial_type_id' => "Campaign Contribution",
));
```

it works OK.  But if I try to specify multiple possible values for financial_type_id, such as:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "id",
  'contact_id' => 2,
  'financial_type_id' => array("Campaign Contribution", "Donation"),
));
```

it generates a SQL error because it creates an invalid WHERE clause:

```
WHERE  ( civicrm_contribution.is_test = 0 AND civicrm_contribution.financial_type_id 0 )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)  LIMIT 0, 25
```

The "civicrm_contribution.financial_type_id 0" should instead be something like "civicrm_contribution.financial_type_id IN (1, 2)"

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
'financial_type_id' => array("Campaign Contribution", "Donation")
```

try

```
'financial_type_id' => array('IN' => array("Campaign Contribution", "Donation"))
```

The API Explorer can generate this code for you if you select the IN operator.

Comment: Yeah, I think that works...but the new API Explorer version generates the incorrect code in my initial post (I don't think it did that on 4.6.0, though I could be wrong.)

I'm waiting for 4.6.3 to fix the bug of Contribution get not using a specified contact ID as a filter, before continuing to troubleshoot the area where this is a problem for us.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the explorer will generate the above (correct) code if you select the "IN" operator. This is generally (but not always) the way to pass multiple values to a "get" operation. Some apis are not entirely consistent with this, hence the explorer's ability to generate code in either format.